Format MUI X DataGrid with many long columns
I want to provide a quick admin tool for my users. I used the Community version of MUI X DataGrid to let them CRUD over a table with 30 columns. I produce a json file containing columns and rows properties on the back end and it's shown on the React front end mostly fine. The problem is all the columns are cut off and it's hard to figure the data. E.g. for columns containing a datetime only the month and the day are visible.
Is there a way to tell the Grid don't truncate the columns if they are under say 300px. That is always show all content, unless the cell contains a very long text - independent of how much the user has to scroll horizontally.
